# Unexpected option config.kit.methodOverride when running Svelte

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently in the middle of a Svelte project and updated to the latest version using the migration tools provided.
However the project no longer interacts with npm.

Running `npm i` will install node modules but returns with this error:

`> Unexpected option config.kit.methodOverride`

and running `npm run dev`gives the following:

```
ERROR Invalid command: dev
 Run `$ svelte-kit --help` for more info.
```

I cannot get passed these two errors, and no other commands through npm work either.

Here is the `package.json`I am working with.

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
        "build": "svelte-kit build",
        "package": "svelte-kit package",
        "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
        "prepare": "svelte-kit sync",
        "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@types/cookie": "^0.4.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
        "eslint": "^8.12.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.5.0",
        "sass": "^1.51.0",
        "svelte": "^3.46.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.2.6",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "~4.6.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.0",
        "@lukeed/uuid": "^2.0.0",
        "cookie": "^0.4.1",
        "svelte-navigator": "^3.2.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you show your `svelte.config.js` file? I think your problem might be there.

Comment: From your package.json, it seems its a SvelteKit project, but you are saying Svelte project. Both have different project setup.

Answer (score 1):

`config.kit.methodOverride` is an older option in SvelteKit's config.
Please make sure your config is correct, the easiest way to do so is to start a new project with `npm create svelte` and compare at least the *package.json* and *sveltekit.config.js* files.